# Show Equation of a Variable Instead of the Answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simple way to show the equation of a var instead of the answer?

Example:
    add = 2 + 2

```
print("ADDITION: " + ?? + " = " + str(add))
```

Replace ?? with whatever to print:

```
ADDITION: 2 + 2 = 4
```

So that I can change the variable and it would still be correct?

Comment: Maybe you want to check out SymPy: http://sympy.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the expression as a string for the "variable representation" you want, and `eval` it to get the "answer".

```
expr = '2 + 2'
print('ADDITION: %s = %s' % (expr, eval(expr))
```

However, "eval is evil", so use it with caution (e.g. don't `eval` an expression you get as an input from the user).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating two variables:

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

then compute the sum:

```
add = 2 + 3
```

and print:

```
print("ADDITION: " + str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = " + str(add))
```

or print it using `format()`

```
print("ADDITION: {} + {} = {}".format(a, b, add))
```